# Create an array from trailing number in each element from another array with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, indexof, charat

I have a

```
var array1 = ["something9","something10","something11"]
```

I simply want to make an array2 from trailing number in each element in array1.

I managed to get the last character using charAt() but I could only get the first element from array1 instead of each element...

Will this be possible in Javascript?

Comment: Try map with a regex

Comment: `array1.map(function(element){ return element.slice(-2); })`

Comment: @Bergi that won't work - the title was misleading. *" simply want to make an array2 with the ending number of each element in array1."*

Comment: @Popnoodles: That's why it's a comment, not an answer :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to iterate over the first array to create the second one.

You can use [Array.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to do it in a simple iteration

```js
var array1 = ["something9", "something10", "something11", 'asdf'];
var array2 = array1.map(function(value) {
  var match = value.match(/\d+$/);
  return match ? match[0] : ''
});

snippet.log(JSON.stringify(array2));
console.log(array2)
```

```html
<!-- Provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

Comment: Nice regex for getting only digits at the end!

Comment: Gives error in Chrome: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of null

Comment: This solution relies on there being a match. Wrapping inner map functionality in a condition would be a fix.

Comment: @M.El-Set see the update... the accepted answer will return an array of arrays - http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/5dcay5ws/1/

Comment: Very nice. Personally, I would go with `return match ? Number(match[0]) : Number.NaN;` since there is an expectation that it will be an array of integers, but that's me being really overboard and probably would cause more troubles than it would solve.

Answer (score 1):

check below

```
var array1 = ["somet34hing9","something10","something11"];
var array2 = array1.map(function(ele){
    return ele.match(/[0-9]+$/g,"");
});
alert(array2);
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/5f4wvudm/1/)

Comment: This will extract all numerical characters within string not just those at the very end, meaning `test5entry123` would return `5123` instead of `123`